# RestSharp - Unable to cast object of System.String to type System.Generic.IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, http, rest

I am new to RestSharp. I have a Restful Service writtein in python which returns a Json message. I wrote a C# client using RestSharp to deserialize the json message to object.

The response content is 
"\"[{\\"coupon\\": 4.5, \\"cusip\\": \\"912810QB7\\", \\"currface\\": 1000000, \\"origface\\": 1000000}]\""

response.data is null.

The inner Exception in response object is
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."

Below are my code:

```
public class QuartzServiceAdapter
{
    const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:7666/ahs/";

    public QuartzServiceAdapter() { }

    public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }

    public List<RootObject> GetBond()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
        request.Resource = "getabond";
        //request.RootElement = "RootObject";
        return Execute<List<RootObject>>(request);
    }
}
```

i created the following object using http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class RootObject
{
    public double coupon { get; set; }
    public string cusip { get; set; }
    public int currface { get; set; }
    public int origface { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas on why the deserialization is failing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a sample of the json being returned?

Comment: Can you use `.Execute()` instead of `.Execute<T>()`? I've been getting similar errors with core data types (e.g. `double`) when using the typed call. In that code path the library attempts to assign your value to an `IDictionary<string,object>` regardless of what type it is.